# JqueryUI Autocomplete: autoFocus = true won't do anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i have this input with autocomplete feature:

```
.autocomplete({
                    source: "jsonR.php",
                    minLength: 2,
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                            $(this).val(ui.item.value);
                            llamar('/includes/router.php?nomenu=1&que=view_item&id='+ui.item.id,'router');
                            return false;
                    },
                    autoFocus: true
                    ,open: function() {
                        $('.ui-autocomplete').addClass('searchBox');
                    } 
            })
```

Basically i want the feature to select the first item so if user hits enter it searches the first one
but this wont hover/focus the first item suggested,

any idea why?

ps: the rest works fine, dough

Comment: check your source.. I tried it with my own source. It worked perfectly.

Comment: There's a much better explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249509/jquery-ui-autocomplete-autofocus-not-working

Answer (score 3):

Scott Gonzalez wrote a selectfirst plugin for this.

See the details here:  http://forum.jquery.com/topic/autocomplete-automatically-select-first-item-in-dropdown-or-add-item-into-drop-down-menu

You can download the plugin here:  https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.selectFirst.js

better yet, here is the source code of the plug-in :)

```
/*
 * jQuery UI Autocomplete Select First Extension
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Scott González (http://scottgonzalez.com)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 *
 * http://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions
 */
(function( $ ) {

$( ".ui-autocomplete-input" ).live( "autocompleteopen", function() {
    var autocomplete = $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ),
        menu = autocomplete.menu;

    if ( !autocomplete.options.selectFirst ) {
        return;
    }

    menu.activate( $.Event({ type: "mouseenter" }), menu.element.children().first() );
});

}( jQuery ));
```

NOTE: to use this simply add this line to your autocomplete:

```
selectFirst: true, // auto selects first element
```

Comment: sweeeeet! with this works but, why doesn't the autoFocus do anythign? thanks!

Comment: Note the `autoFocus: true,` will focus the first element, but not select it.

Comment: I see! i had some concept mix over there... thanks a lot! this works as I need it

Comment: This plugin is no longer maintanted.

Comment: @Cagy79 - should not be an issue since the source is included in the answer.