# Ajax AutoComplete autoFocus not working with .Focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

hope someone can help me with this issue.  When I click on the input text box that the AutoComplete is attached to I want the AutoComplete list to appear unfiltered (before typing any characters).  This works fine until I also add the autoFocus event to the AutoComplete script. I need the autoFocus to select the first value in the list.  This is because I want an option selected without having to select from the list.  This is because if the user types the whole string and it exists in the list, it does not fire the select event (if not selected) which in turn does not retrieve the primary key for the selected string in the AutoComplete list (which I store in a hidden field for later use).

I would like to point out that the autoFocus does focus on the first record for about half a second.

Thanks for your advice in advance.

Here is my code, sorry if it is a bit overkill, but thought it best to send original code.

```
var value = null;

function AutoCompleteList(TextBoxName, HiddenFieldName, ValueFieldName, PrimaryKeyFieldName, TableNameName) {
    $("input[id*= " + TextBoxName + "]").autocomplete({
        autoFocus: true,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Service.asmx/GetListItems",
                data: "{ 'max-height':'10', 'prefix': '" + request.term + "', 'ValueField':'" + ValueFieldName + "', 'PrimaryKeyField':'" + PrimaryKeyFieldName + "', 'TableName':'" + TableNameName + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",

                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('seperatoor')[0],
                            val: item.split('seperatoor')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },


                error: function (response) {
                   // alert(response.responseText);
                },

                failure: function (response) {
                   // alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 0,
        select: function (e, i) {

            $("input[id*= " + TextBoxName + "]").trigger('change');
            $("input[id*= " + HiddenFieldName + "]").val(i.item.val);
            value = i.item.val
        }


    }).focus(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete("search");
    });
};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095856/jqueryui-autocomplete-autofocus-true-wont-do-anything?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my own issue and thought I should post the answer here for anyone else facing the same problem.

The answer was quite simple.  As I could see the autoFocus work for just a moment then disappear (un-select), I knew it was the .Focus event that was disabling it as it works without the .Focus event.  Therefore I simply positioned the autoFocus option for the AutoComplete within the .Focus event, thus firing afterwards.  Here is the revised code.

```
// jQuery
var value = null;

function AutoCompleteList(TextBoxName, HiddenFieldName, ValueFieldName, PrimaryKeyFieldName, TableNameName) {
    $("input[id*= " + TextBoxName + "]").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Service.asmx/GetListItems",
                data: "{ 'max-height':'10', 'prefix': '" + request.term + "', 'ValueField':'" + ValueFieldName + "', 'PrimaryKeyField':'" + PrimaryKeyFieldName + "', 'TableName':'" + TableNameName + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",

                //.ui-autocomplete { height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;} 
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('seperatoor')[0],
                            val: item.split('seperatoor')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },

                error: function (response) {
                    // alert(response.responseText);
                },

                failure: function (response) {
                    // alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 0,
        select: function (e, i) {

            $("input[id*= " + TextBoxName + "]").trigger('change');
            $("input[id*= " + HiddenFieldName + "]").val(i.item.val);
            value = i.item.val
        }
    }).focus(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete("search");
        //I moved the autoFocus option to be triggered here (inside the .Focus event
        $("input[id*= " + TextBoxName + "]").autocomplete({
            autoFocus: true
        })
    });
};
```